# How to rotate texture in opengl Es 2.0 in pixel-level

Tags: android, opengl-es, rotation, opengl-es-2.0, pixel

I'm working with opengl pixel-level (2D)

Everything was fine until I came across the rotation

I have tried different ways and nothing

This is my matrix to work at the level of pixels

```
float[] uScreen =
      {
         2f/width, 0f, 0f, 0f,
         0f, -2f/height, 0f, 0f,
         0f, 0f, 0f, 0f,
        -1f, 1f, 0f, 1f
      };
```

Vertex

```
String vertexSrc =
        "uniform mat4 uScreen;\n" +
        "attribute vec2 aPosition;\n" +
        "void main() {\n" +
        " gl_Position = uScreen * vec4(aPosition.xy, 0.0, 1.0);\n" +
        "}";
```

Fragment shader

```
String fragmentSrc =

    "precision mediump float;\n"+
    "void main(void)\n" +
    "{\n" +
    " gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);\n" +
    "}";
```

This works well and I can draw on screen pixel-level without problems.
But I want to rotate the texture and do not know how

Now try adding the following

```
long time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() % 4000L;
float angleX = 0.090f * ((int) time);

float[] axis = { 1.0f,0.0f,0.0f};

Matrix.rotateM(uScreen,0,angleX,axis[0],axis[1],axis[2]);



GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(uScreenPos, 1, false, uScreen, 0);
```

The texture is rotated, but with a strange behavior, everything rotates around 0.0 on the screen not on its center

Any idea how to rotate this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The texture (Red) rotate over 0,0 pixel no over your center

Comment: It would be helpful to understand, if you post a screenshot of what you are drawing, and what your expected rotated position on the screen is.

Comment: It is as if the camera rotated instead of texture

Answer (score 1):

I multiply the MVP matrix by the rotation matrix, So I needed to move backward rotation matrix and move forward the MVP matrix

This is the solution

```
Matrix.setIdentityM(rotationMat, 0);
Matrix.setRotateM(rotationMat, 0,angleX,1,0,0);
Matrix.translateM(uScreen, 0,sprite.x, sprite.y, 0);
Matrix.translateM(rotationMat, 0,-sprite.x, -sprite.y, 0);
```

Work now :)